# Ergodic Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, law-of-large-numbers

From jacob-Protter: Ergodic Strong Law of Large Numbers

> Let $\tau$ be a one-to-one measure preserving transformation of $\Omega$ onto itself. Assume the only $\tau$-invariant sets are sets of probability $0$ or $1$. If $X \in L^1$ then
> \begin{equation*}
>    \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X(\tau^j(\omega)) = E\{X\}
>   \end{equation*}
> a.s. and in $L^1$.

It is said there that it is a consequence of the Birkhoff ergodic theorem.

Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem from 'Probability Theory A Comprehensive Course (Universitext) (Klenke, Achim)' :

> Let $f = X_0 \in L^1(P)$. Then
> $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f \circ \tau^k \to E\{X_0|\mathcal{I}\} ~~ P-a.s. $$

In showing the ergodic strong law of large numbers, we only have to show that $E\{X_0|\mathcal{I}\} = E\{X_0\}$. Can you please show how prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $Y$ the random variable $E\{X_0|\mathcal{I}\}$. We know that $Y$ is $\mathcal I$-measurable, hence for each $t$, the set $\{Y\leqslant t\}$ has probability zero or one. Therefore, we only need the following:

> If $Y$ is a random variable such that for each $t\in\mathbb R$, $\mathbb P\{Y\leqslant t\}\in\{0,1\}$, then $Y$ is almost surely equal to a constant random variable.

To see this, let $t_0:=\inf\left\{t\in\mathbb R, \mathbb P\{Y\leqslant t\}=1\right\}$. Note that $t_0$ is finite because $\mathbb P\{Y\leqslant t\}=1$ for $t$ large enough. Also, $\mathbb P\{Y\leqslant t_0+1/n\}=1$ by definition of supremum hence $\mathbb P\{Y\leqslant t_0\}=1$. Moreover, $\mathbb P\{Y\leqslant t_0-1/n\}=0$ for each $n$ hence $\mathbb P\{Y\lt t_0\}=0$/

Comment: Hello @DavideGiraudo, shouldn't we say that $Y$ is a.s. constant in the above lemma? Also, I was wondering if the following is true: if $\mathscr{G}$ is $P$-trivial (sets with either zero or one probability), then $E[X|\mathscr{G}]=E[X]$. If this is the case, then this could also be of use to OP

Comment: Hello @Snoop, yes usually there is the abuse of language. Indeed, what you are saying is true.

Comment: Thank you for your proof. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You should have defined $\mathcal{I}$. I guess it is the $\sigma$-algebra of invariant sets.

The hypothesis say that the sets in $\mathcal{I}$ all have measure $0$ or $1$.

You want to pove that $E(X_0|\mathcal{I}) = E(X_0)$ **ALMOST EVERYWHERE**.
You need the fact that $g = E(X_0|\mathcal{I})$ is $\mathcal{I}$-measurable.

---

**Claim:** $g$ is almost everywhere constant.

Partition $\mathbb{R}$ in intervals of length $1/n$. One of those, let us call it $I_n$ is such that $g^{-1}(I_n)$ has measure $1$, because $g$ is $\mathcal{I}$-measurable. Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
  \tau \left(g^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n\right)\right) =
  \tau\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty g^{-1}(I_n)\right) = 1.
\end{equation*}
In particular, $\bigcap I_n$ is non-empty. And therefore, unitary:
\begin{equation*}
\{a\} =
\bigcap I_n.
\end{equation*}
So, $g$ is almost everywhere equal to $a$, because
\begin{equation*}
\tau(g^{-1}(a)) = 1.
\end{equation*}

---

Now, you need to know that $E(E(X_0|\mathcal{I})) = E(X_0)$. This way,
\begin{equation*}
  a = E(g) = E(X_0).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.